# [excel vba]how to change date/hour datatype to text datatype

Tags: excel, vba, ado

As I use ADO to run the VBA SQL, the first row will be attributes automatically.

However, some fields that I got consist of 2 words. To write the SQL statement, I find that I'm unable to call the field with 2 words.

Say field: staff no

My SQL statement:

```
select staff no from [db$]
```

How to solve this?

Comment: SELECT [staff no] FROM [db$]

Comment: But i find that it consists of error .Is it really possibly to contain 2 words field name in ado-sql excel?

Comment: @Vito - [staff no] should work, what is the error you getting?